# GWT 2.4 ValidationTool fails on a Date property on a ValueProxy

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-validation

I was looking around the web for a couple of hours now, but I did not find any hints on this. 
I'm currently in progress of learning GWT (started with 2.4.0), and I'm setting up a RequestFactory. Everything went good until the point I ran the annotation processor.

Here is the relevant proxy class:

```
@ProxyFor(value = PlaylistModel.class)
public interface PlaylistProxy extends ValueProxy {

    Long getPlaylistId();

    String getPlaylistName();

    void setPlaylistName(String playlistName);

    Date getPlaylistStartTime();

    void setPlaylistStartTime(Date playlistStartTime);
}
```

But the annotation processor gives me the following error:

```
error: Could not find domain method similar to java.util.Date getPlaylistStartTime()
error: Could not find domain method similar to void setPlaylistStartTime(java.util.Date)
```

For me it seems that the problem is caused by the java.util.Date return value and parameter, although the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideRequestFactory#transportable) tells that this type is a transportable type.

The type which will be proxied is:

```
public class PlaylistModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7476233813742570809L;

    private Long playlistId;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String playlistName;

    private Date playlistStartDate;

    private ChannelModel channel;

    public Long getPlaylistId() {
        return playlistId;
    }

    public void setPlaylistId(final Long playlistId) {
        this.playlistId = playlistId;
    }

    public String getPlaylistName() {
        return playlistName;
    }

    public void setPlaylistName(final String playlistName) {
        this.playlistName = playlistName;
    }

    public Date getPlaylistStartDate() {
        return playlistStartDate;
    }

    public void setPlaylistStartDate(final Date playlistStartDate) {
        this.playlistStartDate = playlistStartDate;
    }

    public ChannelModel getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(final ChannelModel channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }
}
```

Could anyone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getPlaylistStartTime` vs. `getPlaylistStartDate`

Comment: Looks like it was too late last night when I tried it and I should have noticed this... I'm not at home now but will mark the answer correct when I get home and try this out. Thank you very much!